# asp .net mvc OnResultExecuting modify filterContext Result

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Simple question. How do I go about overriding the OnResultExecuting method in my Controller and force a different ActionResult instead?

Sample code is below. Currently the original ActionResutl continues to execute and my new RedirectResult is ignored.

```
RedirectResult redirectResult = new RedirectResult("http://www.google.com");
filterContext.Result = redirectResult;
base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
```

Answer (score 10):

It would be possible if you override the OnActionExecuted method.

**Example:**

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
  {
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("http://google.com");
      base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to know the exact same thing. I have searched google and came across your question plus others and the responses all seem to be the same. Use the `IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted` method.

However that's not really an answer it more of a work around since as @randy-burden suggests you can modify / replace a RedirectToRouteResult action result in the result filter. So why not a RedirectRoute action result?

If you really want to redirct to a specific url inside the `IResultFilter.OnResultExecuting` method then you can do either of the following:

```
RedirectResult redirectResult = new RedirectResult("http://www.google.com");
filterContext.Result = redirectResult;
filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext);
filterContext.Cancel = true;
base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
```

Or

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectLocation = "http://www.google.com";
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 302;
filterContext.Cancel = true;
base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
```

In the first option you are manually executing the RedirectResult and by doing `filterContext.Cancel = true` you are telling framework that you do not require the `filterContext.Result` to be run. In the second option you are essentially doing the same by but instead of having the RedirectResult configure the Http response you are doing it yourself.

In my case I wanted to append an additional query parameter to the redirect url and telling the framework I wanted to cancel the redirect action result and then redirecting anyway seemed a bit wrong but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to redirect from OnActionExecuting and ended up doing this and it worked:

```
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary
                    {{"controller", "Base"}, {"action", "Error"}, {"errorMessage", errorMessage}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this if you are using MVC5

```
public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `filterContext.Cancel = true`, because otherwise `Headers have been sent` error occurs.