# Why is IIS not returning my error result when the request doesn't come from localhost?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, error-handling

One of my ASP.NET MVC3 controllers sometimes throws an `ApplicationException`.  When it does, the OnException method of my controller's base class executes and sets the filterContext's result:

```
var apiError = filterContext.Exception as APIException;
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = apiError.HTTPStatusCode;
filterContext.Result = JsonError.GetJsonResult(apiError);
```

I know this code is executing; I've stepped through it in the debugger.  But IIS actually serves its error page (the one in inetpub\err...) rather than my JSON response, when the request doesn't come from localhost.  What governs this behaviour?

Custom errors are disabled in web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="Error/ErrorPage.html"></customErrors>
```

Comment: HATE when things work in cassini but not IIS... try iis express?

Comment: Does not your question correlate with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889442/asp-net-mvc-onresultexecuting-modify-filtercontext-result)?

Comment: @felickz both requests are being served by IIS proper.

Comment: @pborovik thanks, but that's not it; I get the behaviour I want when the request comes from my machine, and the undesirable behaviour when I make the same request from another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<customErrors mode="On" ...
```

This did the trick for me. What's confusing is why it works locally independent of this setting.