# Unable to set a new RedirectResult in IResultFilter OnResultExecuting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Does anyone know why the following in the `IResultFilter.OnResultExecuting` method does not work?

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("http://www.google.com");
```

I am not looking for answers on how to redirect from within the `IResultFilter.OnResultExecuting` method as this has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889442/asp-net-mvc-onresultexecuting-modify-filtercontext-result) and to which I've actually provided an answer.

Instead I'm after a reason or logic as to why this doesn't work. It looks like it should work but in Mvc 3 it does not. It would appear that unless you set `filterContext.Cancel = true` then the original ActionResult is executing regardless. This may be a bug specific to Mvc 3 or it may be intentional. However if it is intentional then why?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are already to late, the controller has already been called.

**The base ActionFilterAttribute class has the following methods that you can override:**

- OnActionExecuting – This method is called before a controller action
  is executed.
- OnActionExecuted – This method is called after a controller action is
  executed.
- OnResultExecuting – This method is called before a controller action
  result is executed.
- OnResultExecuted – This method is called after a controller action
  result is executed.

If you want to redirect the user then you should use: OnActionExecuting which is called before a controller action.

Source: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: I can see where you're coming from with this. However whilst the action on the controller has already been 'called' by which I presume you mean executed. The result at this stage has not. And the OnResultExecuting method of a IResultFilter would seem the most appropriate place to affect the ActionResult prior to it being executed. This is especially true if you are targetting a specific type of ActionResult as was in my case where I was trying to add a query parameter to all redirect results.